# Azure functions with Javascript runtime slow to read httptrigger requests

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am sending data (4MB) as gipped request to azure functions with javascript runtime and HttpTrigger. In the function, I decompress the data and process it. It takes 6-7 Seconds to run the code in function but the round trip of request takes almost 60 Seconds. I understand that it takes some time to upload the request but I didn't expect such huge delay. How can I debug where the time is going?

It is not cold start issue as request takes 60 Seconds consistently.

Comment: Hi @ygnr, can you share which version of the Functions runtime you're experiencing this issue on; v1 or v2?

Comment: Hi, out of interest are you using this on a consumption plan or an app service plan?

Comment: It was version 2 and same on both consumption and app service plan.

Comment: After consulting with Microsoft, it turns out that version 2 is the culprit. Changed to v1 and there is no delay.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware Azure Functions doesn't yet support attaching the App Insights Profiler, however you could add your own telemetry.

This won't necessarily help if the time is being spent inside the Azure functions runtime, but it could help alleviate if the bottleneck is during de-compression / processing:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-custom-operations-tracking?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json#outgoing-dependencies-tracking

The general approach for custom dependency tracking is to:

- Call the TelemetryClient.StartOperation (extension) method that fills the DependencyTelemetry properties that are needed for correlation and some other properties (start time stamp, duration).
- Set other custom properties on the DependencyTelemetry, such as the name and any other context you need.
- Make a dependency call and wait for it.
- Stop the operation with StopOperation when it's finished.
- Handle exceptions.

Example from the docs:

```
public async Task RunMyTaskAsync()
{
    using (var operation = telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("task 1"))
    {
        try 
        {
            var myTask = await StartMyTaskAsync();
            // Update status code and success as appropriate.
        }
        catch(...) 
        {
            // Update status code and success as appropriate.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess most of the time is spent inside Azure runtime. So, need a way to see why that is happening.

Comment: You're probably right, but adding the telemetry can help prove it.

Comment: Once you've got to the bottom of it, I'd be interested in which diagnostics techniques you used.

Comment: @ygnr - could you open up an issue with some more details here? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker